# fetching data separated by comma in where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can any one tell me that how i can get name when value is separated by comma in where clause.

This is what i tried:

```
  $this->db->select("seller.name");
  $this->db->from("seller");
  $this->db->where("id",'29,25');
  $q = $this->db->get();
  $res = $q->row_array();
  echo $res['name'] ;
```

I want to print all name with id 29,25 without using another where query
but mine is printing only one with id 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use two ids in where clause than you can use `where_in` like:

```
$this->db->select("name"); 
$this->db->from("seller"); 
$this->db->where_in("id",array(29,25)); 
$q = $this->db->get(); 
$res = $q->result_array();
```

Here ids use as an array `array(29,25)`

For printing the result use `foreach loop`:

```
foreach($res as $value){
    echo "Name: ".$value['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: giving an error undefined index name if i change row_array to result_array

Comment: it worked when i started the started the loop at top

Comment: @SukhwinderSodhi: great, it means, your issue has been resolved??

Comment: yupp thnks for helping